# bit-field in overload resolution for template

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

Anyone knows why the first program compiles but second one doesn't?  The only difference is that the first one uses normal function but the second one uses template function.  Why the overload resolution behaves differently on bitfield for template and non-template function?

Please refer to paragraphs in standard when answering.  Thanks.

a.cpp

```
struct X {
  int x : 20;
  int y : 12;
};

void f(const int& x) {}

void f(int&& x) {}

int main() {
  X x;
  f(x.x);
}
```

b.cpp

```
struct X {
  int x : 20;
  int y : 12;
};

template <typename T>
void f(T&& x) {}

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x) {}

int main() {
  X x;
  f(x.x);
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
[hidden]$ g++ -v 2>&1 | tail -n 1
gcc version 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2) (GCC)
[hidden]$ clang++ -v 2>&1 | head -n 1
clang version 3.3
[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp
[hidden]$ g++ -std=c++11 b.cpp
b.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
b.cpp:14:8: error: cannot bind bitfield ‘x.X::x’ to ‘int&’
[hidden]$ clang++ -std=c++11 a.cpp
[hidden]$ clang++ -std=c++11 b.cpp
b.cpp:14:5: error: non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field 'x'
  f(x.x);
    ^~~
b.cpp:2:7: note: bit-field is declared here
  int x : 20;
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: _MSVC 11_ gets this right, so I'm still unsure if this is a standard defect or a compiler error. Could you try in your compiler the first test case, but replacing `int&& x` with `int& x`?

Comment: @K-ballo: That also fails in gcc.  http://ideone.com/WXJOeg  That MSVC accepts it is no surprise, MSVC improperly binds non-const references to temporaries.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I figured... Now to figure out which compiler has it right

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Actually, _MSVC_ binds to the const reference here.

Comment: @K-ballo: Wow.  Does it also bind to the non-const reference (if you don't give it another choice)?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Nope, it fails to compile in both test cases given no const choice. Interestingly though, it fails to compile `auto&& y = x.x;`.

Comment: Same behavior with cl 16.0 (Visual Studio 2010).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21660/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-k-ballo)

Comment: Do you actually intend to use `int&&` instead of `int&`? From your statements, you don't seem to want to use an rvalue reference..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite clear, you cannot take *non-const references* to *bitfields*. *[class.bit]/3*:

> The address-of operator & shall not be applied to a bit-field, so there are no pointers to bit-fields. A non-const reference shall not be bound to a bit-field (8.5.3). [ Note: If the initializer for a reference of type const T& is an lvalue that refers to a bit-field, the reference is bound to a temporary initialized to hold the value of the bit-field; the reference is not bound to the bit-field directly. See 8.5.3. —end note ]

The reason overload resolution behaves differently has to do with *Universal References*. Reference collapsing rules and templates make this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& x) {}
```

result in `T&&` to be deduced as `int&` when applied to a *non-const lvalue* `int`, which is the case for `x.x`. In that particular case, you are left with:

```
void f(int& x){}
void f(int const& x){}
```

and the first one, the one obtained from reference collapsing rules on `f(T&& x)`, it can be clearly seen to be a better match than the later one.

Comment: Bad asnwer.  That's what I am asking: why overload resolution goes to f(T&&) instead of f(const T&) for template cases, while goes to f(const int&) instead of f(int&&) for normal function cases.

Comment: @icando: When called with an _lvalue_, there are **no** `f(int&&)` overloads due to reference collapsing rules.

Comment: If compiler thinks `const int&` is a better resolution than `int&&`, why doesn't it think `const T&` a better resolution than `T&&`?

Comment: @icando: There is **no** `int&&` overload to resolve to, reference collapsing rules make the templated version be `int&`.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "no `int&&` overload to resolve to"? See: http://pastebin.com/QRnGGmbX, int&& will be resolved if the parameter is rvalue.

Comment: @icando: Do you know about **reference collapsing rules**? Read about them, and you will see how when mixing _templates_ with _rvalue-references_ the type deduction is somewhat different.

Comment: K-ballo, I know reference collapsing rules, but that doesn't answer my problem.  Both `f(T&&)` and `f(const T&)` can be used as resolution, but why compiler chooses `f(T&&)` instead of `f(const T&)`?

Comment: @icando: Because the first one is a better match! Of course... `f(T&&)` will match as `f(int&)`, which is a better match than `f(const T&)`. I'm sure you know how overload resolution works.

Comment: And here I thought a *glvalue* was something, anything with an address (which excludes bitfield members).  Guess not.

Comment: OK, so this is basically a deficit in C++ standard. Bitfield can't be binded to non-const reference, but overload resolution prefer non-const reference to const reference.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I'm not yet proficient in the new _?-values_, would you explain me what you meant with that comment?

Comment: The question remains why `f(int&)` is considered a better match for a bitfield, which it cannot match at all, than `f(const int&)`, which does match, is.

Comment: @K-ballo: The rule of thumb for "is my expression an lvalue or rvalue?" is "if it's a location (has an address), it's an lvalue, otherwise an rvalue".  But that fails here.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Oh, I see your point! `x.x` is no _lvalue_ at all... Is that what you meant?

Comment: @K-ballo: Well, it is (your quote even talks about *lvalue* which is a bitfield), but it doesn't act like one.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Good, then I got it right the first time then... so do you agree this situation would appear to be a defect in the standard?

Comment: I think it's a defect that `f(x.x)` deduces as `int&`, yes.  Because you can't initialize `int&` from `x.x`.  Maybe it needs to be yet another kind of value.

Comment: @BenVoigt we have "glvalue" and "glvalue bitfield" (like we have "prvalue" and "prvalue temporary"). The "bitfield" bit (no pun) is a property of an expression and orthogonal to the value category, currently (and only glvalues can be bitfields). It is a property traced throughout expression analysis and at certain points, things become illformed or are dependent on whether a glvalue is a bitfield or not (like with "temporary").

Comment: @BenVoigt the normative rule is put at 13.3.3.1.4p4: Overload resolution ignores that the glvalue is a bitfield. Much like it ignores that certain conversions are narrowing, or that certain accesses would cause access errors.