# Perfect forwarding workaround for bit-fields

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bit-fields, perfect-forwarding

I’m looking for a workaround for [bit-field in overload resolution for template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026202/bit-field-in-overload-resolution-for-template).

I have a function that I templated for perfect forwarding of its arguments:

```
template <typename... Args> void f(Args &&...args) { }
```

If I try to use it with a bit-field argument, like this:

```
struct bits { unsigned int foo:1; };
bits b{1};
f(b.foo);
```

…it fails to compile:

```
main.cpp:26:7: error: non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field 'foo'
    f(b.foo);
      ^~~~~
```

**Is there a way to overload `f()` such that it takes bit-fields by value but still takes other arguments by reference in the common case?**

So far I haven't been able to. For instance, if I add an overload that takes arguments by value…

```
main.cpp:27:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    f(b.foo);
    ^
```

Comment: There are ways, but I think the _best_ option is to not pass a bitfield.

Comment: @MooingDuck care to add an answer to show some workarounds? the direct approach fails

Comment: @MooingDuck Fancy seeing you here :). I was starting to go this route, it’s as easy as adding a cast at call-time. Not awesome, but not bad either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b694c6cc3a52e0c14bedd6a26790d99d-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc

It can be done, if poorly.  I recommend not doing this.  Basically, the key part is since you can't have a pointer or a reference to a bitfield, you instead use a *lambda* which sets the bitfield for you.

I dislike macros as much as the next guy, but it's the only way I could think of to avoid requiring callers to put in a lambda at the callsite.

```
template<class assigner_type>
struct bitfieldref_type {
    bitfieldref_type(bool value, assigner_type&& assign) :value(value), assign(std::move(assign)) {}
    operator bool() const {return value;}
    bitfieldref_type& operator=(bool v) {assign(v); value=v; return *this;}
private:
    bool value;
    assigner_type assign;
};
template<class assigner_type>
bitfieldref_type<assigner_type> make_bitfieldref(bool value,  assigner_type&& assign)
{return {value, std::move(assign)};}
//macro is optional
#define bitfieldref(X) make_bitfieldref(X, [&](bool v)->void{X=v;})
```

usage:

```
template <class T, typename... Args> void proof_it_works(T&& first) 
{first = 0;}
template <class T, typename... Args> void proof_it_works(T&& first, Args &&...args) {
    first = 0;
    proof_it_works(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}    
template <typename... Args> void f(Args &&...args) {proof_it_works(std::forward<Args>(args)...);}

int main() {
    struct bits { unsigned int foo:1; };
    bits b{1};
    int a = -1;
    float c = 3.14;
    f(a, bitfieldref(b.foo), c);
    std::cout << a << b.foo << c;
    return 0;
}
```

I just noticed that my `bitfieldref_type` assumes the value is a `bool`, instead of a `unsigned int`, but I'll leave fixing that as an excersize for the user.

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be done (at least not how you tried it) because the Standard says so (bold emphasis mine):

**13.3.3.1.4 Reference binding [over.ics.ref]**

> 4 Other restrictions on binding a reference to a particular argument
>   that are not based on the types of the reference and the argument do
>   not aﬀect the formation of a standard conversion sequence, however.
>   [Example: a function with an “lvalue reference to int” parameter can
>   be a viable candidate even if the corresponding argument is an int
>   bit-ﬁeld. The formation of implicit conversion sequences treats the
>   int bit-ﬁeld as an int lvalue and ﬁnds an exact match with the
>   parameter. **If the function is selected by overload resolution, the
>   call will nonetheless be ill-formed because of the prohibition on
>   binding a non-const lvalue reference to a bit-ﬁeld** (8.5.3). — end
>   example ]

This explains why

- the original example fails to compile, because the reference cannot bind to a bit-field
- adding an overload `template<typename... Arg> f(Args.. args)` gave you the ambiguity: overload resoution ended in a tie, and the reference-binding-to-bitfield prohibition never came into play.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best answer I can come up with:

```
template <typename... Args> void f(Args &&...args) { }

struct bits { unsigned int foo:1; };

template <typename T> const T constipate(T v)
{ return(static_cast<const T>(v)); }

void bar()
{
bits b{1};
f(constipate(b.foo));
}
```

EDIT:  There's an easier solution, that eliminates the need for the 'constipate' template:

```
void bar()
{
bits b{1};
f(b.foo + 0);
}
```