# Disable template function if argument is bit field

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I have a template constructor:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if</*blah blah*/>>
Foo(T&& t);
```

And an existing constructor:

```
Foo(bool b);
```

Now, if you call:

```
struct S { int x : 3; };
S s;
Foo(s.x);
```

You get `non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field t`. See: [bit-field in overload resolution for template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026202/bit-field-in-overload-resolution-for-template?rq=1) as to why, but why is out of scope for this question.

I am perfectly fine with just disabling the perfect-forwarding constructor for bitfields. Is there any compile-time way to check if `T` is a bit-field?

Comment: When you say bit-field, what are you asking about?  Is it a class type that contains bit-field members?

Comment: *non-const reference cannot bind to bit-field t, which makes some sense* Not for me, since I see no code.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to force the constructor template to be removed from overload resolution when the argument is a bit field. If you provide more detail about what these constructors should do, maybe we can suggest alternative options.

Comment: +super, I updated the question with a reference to why it fails, but why it fails is out of scope of the question. I just want to disable a template if the type is a bitfield.

Comment: If you are looking to disable it, then maybe that's the answer to your question: DON'T DO IT; it is not valid for your use-case. Or maybe you want an overload, then you should update your question

Comment: +NathanOliver: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field
+Brian: Its a perfect forwarding constructor used to initialize a composit type. I can disable the constructor for a ton of other reasons, not being able to disable bit-types seems like a good feature request (though bitfield use is admittedly rare).

Comment: +smac I only want to disable it if T is a bit-field type, it would be very useful for other types.

Comment: Bit field are not really a type. They belong to a structure. You cannot have a function that has bit field arguments.

Comment: +phil1970 Yes, that is true. You can, however, pass a bit field into a function, which mucks up perfect forwarding constructor. While there is no way to specify it as a "type", it is a type in the mind of the compiler. See the linked question above.

I don't want to have a function with a bit field argument, I want the compiler to stop *trying* to make a function with a bit-field argument. My perfect-forwarding constructor to tries to accept a bit field, it accepting a bit field causes compiler errors, and I want to stop that.