# Overloading function template error cannot bind bit-field ‘s.S::i’ to ‘int&’

Tags: c++, templates

1. Why doesn't this code f(s.i) bind to the second template f(const T&
   op) ?
2. Why is it giving a compile error ?
3. Changing the first f(T&& op) to f(const T&& op) fixes the error.
4. Why isn't SFINAE happening at line 5 and then it goes on to find the
   correct line 8 ?

````
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> void f(const T&& obj){ cout <<"rvalue\n"; }
template<typename T> void f(const T& obj){ cout <<"lvalue\n"; }

struct S {
    int i:31;
    int j;
};
int main()
{
    S s;
    f(s.i);
}

navin@Navin-acer-5740:~/cpp$ !g++
g++ bitfield_rvalue.cpp 
bitfield_rvalue.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bitfield_rvalue.cpp:17:13: error: cannot bind bit-field ‘s.S::i’ to ‘int&’
   17 |         f(s.i);
      |           ~~^
```
````

Comment: please post the code without the line numbers so that others can copy it to reproduce the error

Comment: when the function signature is `const T& op` then `T` is deduced as plain `int` on `f(s.i)`

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with SFINAE. [Demo without SFINAE](https://godbolt.org/z/a9c1K43ze). Also see [bit-field in overload resolution for template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026202/bit-field-in-overload-resolution-for-template)

Comment: bit-fields don't have unique memory location, so you should not try get a pointer or reference to it (it's illegal, but some compilers oblige). In fact, a bit-field type is a unique type catheogy, unrelated to its integral counterpart.

Comment: Read about the **bit-fields** special value category: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category